# Search for an object in a queue without any imports

Tags: java, string, search, queue

I have a Java program that uses scanner input to insert value in my circular queue, but i have to create a search method **without using any imports**.

For example:

```
public Projects(String sname, String name, int timeLeft)
Projects p = new Projects("ST1", "Title1", 16);
q.insert(p);
Projects r = new Projects("ST2", "Title1", 16);
q.insert(r);
```

After inserting the element in my circular queue, I have to use the search method that will allow the user to input the search criteria to search for the String `sname` and displaying the position concatenated with the `sname` variable.

Is there any way that this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible to find and know the position in the queue of a specific piece of information you just need to program a search function.

In this example the name list will equal your queue class

```
public void search(list head,  string sname)
{
     boolean found = false;
     int pos = 0;
     list current = head;
   while(!found)           
   {
       //iterate through the list looking for the sname
       //for each node you do not find it 
       //if found change found to true.
       pos++;
       if(!found)
            current = current.next; //iterate to next node
       if(current.sname == head.sname)  //if it made it all the way around without finding the node
           break;  //this prevents an infinite loop.
    }
 if(found) //found = true
    //put output of what you need here.
 if(!found) //found = false
    //output not found message.
```

as this is most likely a homework assignment I did not give you the whole answer you will have to program in the rest to complete the program.

Comment: if you actually need to return the node change return type to your queue class type and return the node if found.